# Rails no method error for empty relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

i just get an error.

i got a has many assotiations, but when filling a form, i leave the field empty, and ir returned me an error:

```
 Showing /home/techmago/namebook/app/views/names/index.html.erb where line #16 raised:

undefined method `nome' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #16):

13: <% @names.each do |name| %>
14:   <tr>
15:     <td><%= name.nome %></td>    
16:     <td><%= name.family.nome %></td>
17:     <td><%= name.race.nome %></td>
18:     <td><%= h(name.descr).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %></td>
19:     <td>
```

I am sure that is because one of the name.family.nome is nill. I would like that this situation could be accepted

Models:

```
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :family
  belongs_to :race
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books

  attr_accessible :descr, :family_id, :nome, :race_id, :book_ids

  validates :nome, presence: true
end

class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :names
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
  has_and_belongs_to_many :races

  attr_accessible :descr, :nome, :book_ids, :race_ids

  validates :nome, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what we know is that that `name`, in particular, doesn't have an associated `family` object. That is, `name.family` is returning `nil`, which doesn't respond to `nome`, as indicated by the error. So, if what you're looking for is that this be handled gracefully... i.e. don't error and don't show anything in this case, you can do this:

```
<%= name.family.try(:nome) %>
```

The `try` block will return `nil` if `name.family` is `nil` and then the erb block will return an empty string, basically.

Otherwise, you'll need to figure out why one of the `name`s in the loop doesn't have a `family` and go from there.

Comment: Was just that! thanx!